# Checking multiple rows against each other in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of buildings with various information pertaining to them, such as `address`, `building_id`, etc.

I also have a table of reports containing anything that could be wrong with any of those buildings. (This table is massive, since every report gets dumped here.) Each report has a status of 0 = closed or 1 = active.  Note: `building_id` is also in each record so it can be tied together that way.

The last part is the person is logged in with an id, which controls which buildings the person sees to begin with.

What i want to do is build a list of buildings that have open reports.  Right now it's set up to run a query to get all buildings with the `user_id`; then run a query to get all open reports.

The line of thinking i had was this:

```
SELECT *
FROM buildings
WHERE user_id = $currentUser AND (SELECT * FROM reports WHERE building_id = $buildingID and (count reports > 0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM buildings b
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT building_id FROM reports WHERE status = 1) r
ON B.building_id = r.building_id
```

Comment: Good choice on the INNER JOIN, but why keep the subquery? It won't be able to utilize indexes that way.

Answer (score 0):

Without further knowledge of your schema... try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE user_id = $currentUser AND building_id IN 
(SELECT distinct building_id FROM reports WHERE status = 1)
```